# I want to understand how to solve this problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What are the answers to prove that for sets A,B and C.

$1-$ If A ⊆ B and B ⊆ C then A ⊆ C

$2-$ If A ⊆ B and B ⊂ C then A ⊂ C

$3-$ If A ⊂ B and B ⊆ C then A ⊂ C

$4-$If A ⊂ B and B ⊂ C then A ⊂ C ?

Comment: Apply the definition of $\subseteq$ : $x \in A \to x \in B$, for every $x$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out here that some authors will use $\subset$ to mean any subset, including improper subsets.  In other words, some authors will say that $A\subset A$ is true.  Given that both the symbols $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ appear here, we should assume that the author instead intends $\subset$ to be used exclusively for proper subsets.  The properties should all be expected and familiar, just how if we were to replace these sets with numbers and the subset relations with inequalities, we have $a\leq b$ and $b\leq c$ implies $a\leq c$, that if $a<b$ and $b\leq c$ that $a<c$, etc...